# Hibernate collection loaded by custom SQL

Tags: sql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have some problems trying to get a bag collection of a class to be loaded through custom sql.
Here's the xml mappings I have for my class

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="alekso.npe.model.Utente" table="VNPEZZ_UTE_MAT" lazy="false">
    <id name="matricola" column="C_UTE_MAT">             
    </id>       
    <property name="nome" column="T_NOM" />
    <property name="cognome" column="T_COG" />
    <property name="email" column="T_EML" />

    <bag name="ruoli" table="VNPEZX_UTE_APP_TRN" 
        inverse="false" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all" >
        <key column="C_UTE_MAT" />
        <one-to-many class="alekso.npe.model.Ruolo" />
        <loader query-ref="rolesQuery"/>
    </bag>
</class>
    <class name="alekso.npe.model.Ruolo" table="VNPEZH_TIP_USR"
    lazy="false" where="C_APP = 'NPE'">
    <id name="codice" column="C_TIP_USR">            
    </id>   
    <property name="nome" column="T_DES_TIP_USR"/>      

</class>
<sql-query name="rolesQuery">
    <return alias="role" class="alekso.npe.model.Ruolo"></return>
    <load-collection alias="ruoli" role="alekso.npe.model.Ruolo" ></load-collection>
    <![CDATA[select {ruolo.*}
    from NPEA.vnpezx_ute_app_trn permesso join NPEA.vnpezh_tip_usr ruolo
      on ruolo.c_tip_usr = permesso.c_tip_usr
      where permesso.c_app = 'NPE'
      and permesso.c_ute_mat = :matricola ]]>
</sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

But when I run the application I get an error:
`org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: rolesQuery` in the buildSessionFactory phase.
Can you tell me what's wrong with this mapping?
I tried both with and without the `<return>` tag inside the `<sql-query>` but it still don't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the error... the line `<load-collection alias="ruoli" role="alekso.npe.model.Ruolo" ></load-collection>` inside the custom query definition gives the error.
Without that line, everything works fine (almost... the collection of roles is lazy loaded even if I set lazy="false" everywhere).
But that line I removed is on the documentation, so I'd like to know why it's wrong.
I'll leave the question open for other to give some hints on this.

Comment: Come across into any insight into the lazy loading issue?